# Get exact country and city of a web visitor (in drupal 8 or PHP native)

Tags: php, geolocation, location, drupal-8

I need for my website to know the real and accurate location of a visitor to offer him / her near elements.

I am trying to consume various external services and they tell me that I am located in barcelona (when I l live in Madrid).

These are the services I am consuming:

- http://www.geoplugin.net/xml.gp?ip=5.225.20.136
- https://whatismycountry.com/
- http://www.ipinfodb.com/my_ip_location.php
- http://www.ip2location.com/

Know any service or any way in PHP to get exact location data?

Comment: You should try the HTML5 geolocation. Please visit http://www.geolocation.com for more information. However, it is not a PHP service.

Comment: Camilo Go - I already explained what I want to do:
Knowing which city and country is the visit to be able to offer elements of my website as close as possible to the visitor.
Get a city and make a query to my database to obtain records of that city (or near that city by means of location)

Comment: Michael C - I have entered gelocation.com and it tells me that I am from Barcelona (when I am in Madrid). Why is the location not correct in all of these services or tools? Does it give you a correct location?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid this is not possible.

The best way to go about solving this is to use javascript and get longitude and latitude from the visitor of your site. This, of course, requires the visitors device to have such abilities. Read more about this at [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation).

If your visitors device does not support this method, use IP Geo location as a fallback. The problem with this is that it is not reliable as you have discovered. I live near Bergen in Norway, and if I use IP to geolocate my phone, it always shows that I am in Oslo. This is due to my cell phone operator of course, but this is also a problem with other services giving you IP addresses. You can read more about how accurate IP Geo location is at [WhatsMyIPAddress.com](http://whatismyipaddress.com/geolocation-accuracy).

Lastly, always give the user the ability to give you their location when visiting your site.